# Pinch zoom for the video

Tags: java, android, video, zooming, android-videoview

I want to make a pinch zoom for a video, I have right now zoom in the video, but it works not correctly, it scale video not in the place where fingers touched, but in the left corner of the video, how to fix it?

How it looks right now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VufMUJaV2Nk

Code of MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // minimum video view width
    static final int MIN_WIDTH = 100;
    // Root view's LayoutParams
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams mRootParam;
    // Custom Video View
    private VodView mVodView;
    // detector to pinch zoom in/out
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;
    // detector to single tab
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    private String vidAddress= "rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/definst/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRootParam = (LayoutParams) ((View) findViewById(R.id.root_view)).getLayoutParams();
        mVodView = (VodView) findViewById(R.id.vodView1);
        // Video Uri
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
        mVodView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        // set up gesture listeners
        mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new MyScaleGestureListener());
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MySimpleOnGestureListener());
        mVodView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mVodView.start();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mVodView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private class MySimpleOnGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            if (mVodView == null)
                return false;
            if (mVodView.isPlaying())
                mVodView.pause();
            else
                mVodView.start();
            return true;
        }

    }

    private class MyScaleGestureListener implements OnScaleGestureListener {
        private int mW, mH;

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // scale our video view
            mW *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mH *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            if (mW < MIN_WIDTH) { // limits width
                mW = mVodView.getWidth();
                mH = mVodView.getHeight();
            }
            Log.d("onScale", "scale=" + detector.getScaleFactor() + ", w=" + mW + ", h=" + mH);
            mVodView.setFixedVideoSize(mW, mH); // important
            mRootParam.width = mW;
            mRootParam.height = mH;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mW = mVodView.getWidth();
            mH = mVodView.getHeight();
            Log.d("onScaleBegin", "scale=" + detector.getScaleFactor() + ", w=" + mW + ", h=" + mH);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            Log.d("onScaleEnd", "scale=" + detector.getScaleFactor() + ", w=" + mW + ", h=" + mH);
        }
    }
}
```

Custom View:

```
public class VodView extends VideoView {

    public VodView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VodView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VodView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    /**
     * Resize video view by using SurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(...). See {@link android.view.SurfaceHolder#setFixedSize}
     * @param width
     * @param height
     */
    public void setFixedVideoSize(int width, int height)
    {
        getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.attracti.scalevideo.MainActivity" >

    <com.example.attracti.scalevideo.VodView
        android:id="@+id/vodView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```